# Not Nullable fields in SQL Server Still Considered Required Fields in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ssms

I have a non nullable fields in a table with default values set already in the property "Default Value or Binding" in SSMS. I linked this table in an ASP.Net mvc application. When I created the view and when running the create view, it still asking me to enter the required fields for the non nullable fields even though i assigned a default value for them.

After this I removed the line:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.position, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

which is bellow each 
`@Html.EditorFor` statement, but this time it post me back to the same page with no changes in the database.

How can I get rid of the message in the required fields as I have already default value for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can create a constructor in your model. It will initialize default values once new instance is created. If user provides that fields, then it will be overridden. If no, value from constructor will be passed to EF.

What you are trying to do now, won't work according to specifications: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187872.aspx

[Here](http://lancelarsen.com/entity-framework-code-first-computed-getdate/) you can see how to achieve what you want, considering that this field will always be generate in database.

Comment: Here's my class
public partial class Category
    {      [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressM...
        public Category()
        {
            this.id_parent = 0;
            this.id_shop_default = 0;
        }
        public int id_category { get; set; }
        public int id_parent { get; set; }
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public int? id_shop_default { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    } '
I get this error when I run it: 
Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Comment: How can I see the validation error? "See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details"

Comment: I managed to see the errors and they're: 
WebApplication1.Model.Category failed validation
- level_depth : The level_depth field is required.
- nleft : The nleft field is required.
- nright : The nright field is required.
- date_add : The date_add field is required.
- date_upd : The date_upd field is required.
- position : The position field is required.

I am sure I entered those values in the constructor.

Comment: this means the constructor is not being called.

Comment: Somehow I managed to get it working, but I am not getting an error message when user input letters in a numeric textbox, why?

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the many reasons not to use entity models as viewmodels. MVC doesn't care that the required field has a default value, that information is database-related and not related to input validation.

Introduce a viewmodel where those properties are not required, and map the posted viewmodel to your entity model.

So, given an entity model that looks like this:

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    // this property is not-nullable in the database
    [Required]
    public string SomeRequiredDatabaseField { get; set; }
}
```

Because the `SomeRequiredDatabaseField` is `NOT NULL`, it is annotated as such by Entity Framework, even if it has a default value. MVC will pick up this annotation, and consider the model not valid when the property has no value.

Now if you introduce a viewmodel, you can tell MVC that this property is not required:

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    // Not required
    public string SomeRequiredDatabaseField { get; set; }
}
```

Now in your controller, you map the viewmodel to the entity model (preferably using AutoMapper):

```
public ActionResult Post(SomeViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var entityToSave = new SomeEntity
        {
            SomeRequiredDatabaseField = model.SomeRequiredDatabaseField
        };

        db.SomeEntity.Add(entityToSave);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: How? Whats the difference if i go to my table in ssms and change the required field into allow null?

Comment: I don't understand that question.

Comment: I mean: "do u mean i go to ssms and make all the fields in my table accept null value?"

Comment: No, you introduce a viewmodel and map that to your entity, which is exactly what I explained in my answer.

Comment: How? Im still new to mvc. Do u have some online link where i can learn this?